# Configure wallaby for React-redux-es6-typescript-immutable applications

Tags: wallaby.js

How to configure wallaby for React-redux-es6-typescript-immutable application. I use webstorm editor. My base code is committed [here](https://github.com/AmalaLiza/task-tracker)

I tried the following code in wallaby.js, but it throws

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: exports

at src/store.ts:3

```
module.exports = function (wallaby) {

    return {
        files: [
            'src/*.ts'
        ],

        tests: [
            'test/*Spec.ts'
        ],

        compilers: {
            '**/*.ts': wallaby.compilers.typeScript({
                module: 5,  // ES6
                target: 2  // ES6
            })
        },
        preprocessors: {
            '**/*.js': file => require('babel-core').transform(
                file.content,
                {sourceMap: true, presets: ['es2015']})
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like your application is using CommonJs (and Webpack) so you need to configure wallaby.js to use webpack like described here http://wallabyjs.com/docs/integration/webpack.html

Comment: adding env variable did the work. my working wallaby config is as below: module.exports = function (wallaby) { return { files: [ 'src/*.ts' ], tests: [ 'test/*Spec.ts' ], env: { type: 'node' }, compilers: { '\*/.ts': wallaby.compilers.typeScript({ module: 1 }) } } }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have more or less the same setup as you. Did you try setting the `env` variable to `node`?

My working wallaby.js config file for babel 6 is the following:

```
module.exports = function() {
  return {
    files: [
      {pattern: "src/**/*.js*"}
    ],

    tests: [
      {pattern: "tests/integration/*.js"}
    ],

    env: {
      type: "node"
    },

    preprocessors: {
      "**/*.js": file => require("babel-core").transform(file.content, {sourceMap: true, presets: ["es2015"]})
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: adding env variable did the work. thanks :)
my working wallaby config is as below:

    module.exports = function (wallaby) {

        return {
            files: [
                'src/*.ts'
            ],

            tests: [
                'test/*Spec.ts'
            ],

            env: {
                type: 'node'
            },

            compilers: {
                '**/*.ts': wallaby.compilers.typeScript({
                    /* 1 for CommonJs*/
                    module: 1
                })
            }
        }
    }